# How can I create custom method comment template in Android Studio

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio

I've looked for it all over the menu, but failure. The document of IntelliJ IDEA also mention this part

Comment: Do you mean the template for JavaDoc comments? What exactly would you like to configure there?

Comment: Yes， for JavaDoc comments

Comment: What exactly would you like to configure there?

Comment: The default method comment is like